# Install Windows 8 to last partition on drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a laptop with Ubuntu installed. I wanted to Dual boot Windows 8, but i came across a problem.

My drive is partition as follows

```
Drive 0 Partition 1 27.9gb 0.0MB free Logical //my root partition
Drive 0 Partition 2 93.1gb 0.0MB free Logical //my /home partition
Drive 0 Partition 3 3.8 gb 0.0MB free Logical //my swap partition
Drive 0 Partition 4 413.8gb 273.5gb free Primary //ntfs storage partition
Drive 0 Unallocated Space 160gb
```

Now when I try to create partition from unallocated space, nothing happens. Also when i try to install Windows to Partition 4 I get

```
Windows can't be installed on this drive.
```

Comment: Windows wants desperately to be the only OS on the system. The easiest way to do a dual-boot install is always to install Windows first.

Comment: So no way to do this without erasing Ubuntu? I would survive deleting Ubuntu, but removing this NTFS partition would be huge waste of time because I would have to backup everything, and then take it back

Comment: If I was sure there was no way without wiping the drive first, I'd have made that an answer. Chances are, there are indeed some workarounds for this. My comment was just to note, for future reference, that setting up a clean system for dual-boot usually goes best if Windows is loaded first.

Comment: @Iszi You can install Windows after Ubuntu. (But you need to restore GRUB later.)

Comment: I know I can, but I never tried installing windows to partition after Ubuntu partitions on drive. This won't seem to work

Comment: @Iszi please don't say that windows wants to be the only operating system because point blank that's 100% false

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, to be more clear: *Microsoft* wants Windows to be the only OS you use, so (at least historically) Windows installation processes were made with the assumption that this would be the case.

Comment: To my knowledge - windows will always try to sit in the primary partitions - and 4 primary partitions are allowed per HDD. In your case the first 3 are logical and _partition 4_ is Primary. With some 3rd party partitioning tool try to create a primary partition with the _unallocated space_ of 160GB - then try installing windows. Anyway as @Iszi said this will remove your GRUB and put windows boot loader. Later you have to manually install GRUB to dual boot. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I can't install to Primary partition either. As you can see I already have primary partition, but it still isn't working. It should create 350MB system partition

Comment: @lszi you still seem to be telling straw men statements.  Windows works perfectly with other operating systems If Microsoft wanted to block dual booting they could very easily

Comment: @Ramhound I'm fully aware that Windows works fine with other OSs (I've done a few dual-boot systems myself), and I'm sure Microsoft isn't *actively* trying to prevent dual-booting. However, this doesn't mean they're going to go out of their way to make dual-booting any easier either. This is why dual-boot schemes involving Windows *always* go easier when Windows is installed first and why, as YtvwlD mentioned, to do otherwise requires (at minimum) that you re-install the boot loader after Windows is installed.

Comment: If you have MSDOS partition scheme there can be only four primary partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a MSDOS partition scheme?

Then you can only create up to four (4) primary partitions.

Your solution would be to move the data of the last partition away, then create a extended partition and inside of it a logical of the same size as the old one and move the data back.

Then you are able to create more logical partitions and install some systems inside of it.

**Warning:** *I have only tried that with installing Ubuntu in a logical partition. I am not sure, if this will work with windows.*